# How to prevent interruption of a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, qthread

I have multiple threads in my program, and one of them is reading from 2 cameras using OpenCV.  I want to guarantee that the camera thread is not interrupted while capturing the frames from the two cameras so that the frames are captured at essentially the same time.  How can I prevent the thread from being interrupted in the middle of reading the frames?

To better explain my question, I've provided some example code:

```
import cv2
import time
cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #setup first camera
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1) #setup second camera

while True:
  disable_interrupts() #prevent task switching to other threads
  cap0.grab() #capture a frame
  cap1.grab() #capture a frame
  timestamp = time.time() #the approximate time the frames were captured
  enable_interrupts() #allow task switching to continue

  ret, frame0 = cap0.retrieve() #get the previously "grabbed" frame for the first camera
  ret, frame1 = cap1.retrieve() #get the previously "grabbed" frame for the second camera
```

I'm used to working with microcontrollers without an OS and you often switch tasks using interrupts.  It is easy in that case, because you simply disable some/all interrupts, execute the critical code, and then re-enable the interrupts afterward.  Is there something equivalent in the operating system world?  Or does OpenCV offer something for capturing multiple cameras simultaneously?  I happen to be using QThread (PyQt4), so does QThread offer anything like this?

Comment: You might be better off using processes

Comment: Am I missing something? I see no threading in your code

Comment: I intended the code to show that I needed to capture the frames at the same time without interruption so I didn't bother adding the code to show multiple threads.  I just assumed people could imagine another thread exists that could interrupt the while loop.